# How to add the content of a text file into a mySQL database,the file content is given

Tags: php

ConnID        Source IP:Port          Dest IP:Port            PeerID Accel RR
114145       22.0.4.187:2011      192.168.37.3:445 00:0c:29:de:1e:6d TCDL  00.0%
491114       22.0.4.163:2013      192.168.37.3:445 00:0c:29:de:1e:6d TCDL  00.0%
323469       22.0.4.144:2127      192.168.37.3:445 00:0c:29:f1:07:41 TCDL  00.0%
321395        22.0.4.37:2087      192.168.37.3:445 00:0c:29:de:1e:6d TCDL  00.0%
303508        22.0.4.30:2073      192.168.37.3:445 00:0c:29:f1:07:41 TCDL  00.0%
127701        22.0.7.36:2066      192.168.37.3:445 00:0c:29:f1:07:41 TCDL  00.0%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a field in your table to store the text file with one of the following data types:

VARCHAR(1 to 255) - for up to max 255 characters
VARCHAR(MAX) - for the maximum charaters your machine can handle
TEXT can store 65,535 characters (approx 64KB)
MEDIUMTEXT = 16,777,215 characters (approx 16 MB) 
LONGTEXT = 4,294,967,295 chars (approx 4GB)

Then read the data in the text file serially or randomly using an IO stream or its just the data above, just copy paste directly into the field.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this out. The FIRST thing you should do is try to delimit your serial, concurrent text file above so that you can start working with things instead of one continuous string. Import into Excel as a text file using SPACE or " " (with a space between the double quotes) as the delimiter. Then go through the imported contents and fix any faulty data.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code. It will helps you.

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("text_file_name.txt", "r"); //read line one by one
$values='';

while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
{
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); // Read a line.
    list($a,$b,$c)=explode("|",$buffer);//Separate string by the means of |
    //values.=($a,$b,$c);// save values and use insert query at last or

    // use mysql insert query here
}
?>
```